# Slots Creation based on date and time(float) field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

[image]I have two date field.

**from_date** and
**to_date**
In One2many line item, there is three float fields

**from_time** ,**to_time** and **interval**

Slot have to be created based on the above parameters.

Example:

```
from_date = '2017-07-21'
to_date = '2017-07-21'
```

the duration is one day.
The One2many line items have the values

```
from_time = 9.0
to_time = 10.0
interval = 30(in minutes)
```

The output should generate two slots

```
1. '2017-07-21 09:00:00' '2017-07-21 09:30:00'
2. '2017-07-21 09:30:00' '2017-07-21 10:00:00'
```

It should generate two line items.

If the duration is for week.
it should generate 2 * 7 = 14 slots.

I have used the code which generates for one day.

```
@api.one
def generate(self):
    cr = self.env.cr
    uid = self.env.uid
    context = self.env.context
    event = self.pool.get('calendar.event')
    slot = self.pool.get('slot.booking')
    old_data_id = slot.search(cr, uid, [('slot_id', '=',self.id)], context=context)
    slot.unlink(cr, uid ,old_data_id)
    for each in self.shift_line:
        if each.interval > 60 or each.interval == 0:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Attention!'), _('Please enter interval timings in minutes range like (10-60) '))
        interval = each.interval
        fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
        start_date = datetime.strptime(self.from_date, fmt)
        end_date = datetime.strptime(self.to_date, fmt)
        days = []
        date = start_date
        pdb.set_trace()
        str_start_time = '%s %s' % (self.from_date,'{0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(each.from_time * 60, 60)))+':00'
        str_end_time = '%s %s' % (self.from_date,'{0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(each.to_time * 60, 60)))+':00'
        time = datetime.strptime(str_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end = datetime.strptime(str_end_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        while date <= end_date:
            hours = []
            while time <= end:
                hours.append(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                time += timedelta(minutes=interval)
            date += timedelta(days=1)
            time += timedelta(days=1)
            end += timedelta(days=1)
            days.append(hours)
        print "\n\n\n\n\nn\+++++++++++++++++++++days",days
        for hours in days[0][:-1]:
            val = datetime.strptime(hours, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            val = val + timedelta(minutes=interval)
            values = {
                'name' : 'Slot for ' + self.employee_id.name,
                'start_datetime' : hours,
                'stop_datetime' : str(val),
                'slot_id' : self.id,
                'shift_lines_id' : each.id,
                'partner_id': self.employee_id.id,
                'duration' : each.interval,
                }
            print "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++values",values
            slot.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

Any help for multiple days is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using text and float values instead of datetime types?

Comment: Why do you mix up old and new API? You don't need `cr, uid and context` on every call anymore.

Comment: @CZoellner True. I will remove

Comment: @klaus-d I am using float values for time because, in main class there will be two date fields. But in One2many field there will be multiple line items based on shifts. So required to enter in float fields.

Comment: Provided above screenshot in question.May be you can understand better @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

```
ist_timedelta = timedelta(seconds=((time in seconds)-10800))
```

adding this will give the exact answer, here 10800 is because of 3 hours difference of UTC to KSA.